# not able to intall or use in react native sockjs-client or stompjs

Tags: react-native, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "stompjs";

i am installing both the library for the websocket in react native for C/S communication
but npm getting error

import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "stompjs";

i want both library alternative in react native cli for mobile app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.